# Create customized DateTimeField

Tags: django

I am trying to implement a restaurants website to practice using Django.
In models.py, I have a class called `RestaurantLocation`,with the following lines:

```
class RestaurantLocation(models.Model):
    updated   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I attempt to add a field `visited` to represent the first time I visited it.
To accomplish it,I look through 'DateTimeField' `DateField` in django documentation.
There are only two methonds of `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` without options to setup my own datetime.

How to customize DateTimeField for my own datetime?

Comment: use DateTimeField without any parameters

Comment: The parameters for the datetime field only define default values. You can always pass in custom values in the form of a date and time string or a `datetime` object at the time of creating an instance of the model

Comment: I leave params empty.When `makemigrations`,it reminds to enter default value `Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the DateTimeField without any params,
means set `null=True`,`blank=True`

```
visited   = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```